# Java, unparsable date error, converting from String to Date

Tags: java, date

I have this String `"2019-10-17T16:00:00+02:00"` and I want to convert this `String` to a `Date` object, because I want to change the format. I tried this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sd1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
Date dt = sd1.parse(mystring);
SimpleDateFormat sd2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String newDate = sd2.format(dt);
System.out.println(newDate);
```

But I have this message: Unparseable date: "2019-10-17T16:00:00+02:00"

What can I do? 
Thank you all

Comment: FYI, you are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

Comment: Why the downvote, please? Lack of search and research? The question has minimal, reproducible example with expected behaviour and observed result, which is pretty good for a relatively new Stack Overflow user.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of being *up to **date***:
Please consider using the modern date and time API `java.time`.
You can easily parse and format dates, times and date times using it.

See this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String d = "2019-10-17T16:00:00+02:00";
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(d, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z")));
}
```

The output is this:

```
2019/10/17 16:00:00 +0200
```

That formatter is used be default, so no need to specify. The standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats are used by default in *java.time*.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-10-17T16:00:00+02:00" ) // ISO 8601 formats can be parsed directly, without specifying a `DateTimeFormatter` object.
```

If you just want to extract the date part of a date time, then you can do that, too by just applying two additional lines of code:

```
LocalDate date = odt.toLocalDate();
System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
```

Comment: No need for the formatter object. The input complies with ISO 8601, and can be parsed by default with `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for extending my answer with useful information!

Answer (score 2):

The pattern letter for ISO 8601 time zones is `X` not `Z` as others have noted.

Use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sd1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
```

And parsing will succeed.